# How to integrate npm package written in Angular inside react application

Tags: reactjs, angular, micro-frontend

[Trying to implement npm package  written in angular inside react application but it is throwing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkJov.png)

link to error msg:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbg2N.png)

link to npm library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-widget-v1

import {TestWidgetV1Component} from 'test-widget-v1'

Can someone help how to fix this errors?

is there any approach to integrate angular inside react application via npm packages?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your objective here. Could you please provide a minimalistic project on StackBlitz where I can replicate the same error you're encountering?

Comment: please check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-utwa75?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2FApp.tsx&title=React%20Starter @RavikumarRajendran